# Conditional Independence on Sigma Fields vs Conditional Independence on Events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

I am having some trouble with the measure theoretic notion of conditional independence. In particular, it intuitively seems to me that if $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are conditionally independent with respect to $\sigma(Z)$, then it should be that for any $A \in \sigma(X)$, $B \in \sigma(Y)$, and $C \in \sigma(Z)$ we have $$P(A\cap B| C) = P(A|C)P(B|C).$$ Yet, I am having quite a bit of difficulty proving this statement.

Note: I take $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are conditionally independent with respect to $\sigma(Z)$ to mean that $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent on the $\sigma$-field, $\sigma(Z)$, so that for any $U \in \sigma(X)$, $V\in \sigma(Y)$, we have that $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent w.r.t. $\sigma(Z)$ if we have $P(U\cap V|\sigma(Z)) = P(U|\sigma(Z))P(V|\sigma(Z))$ $P$-a.s.

Comment: What is the definition of "$\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are conditionally independent with respect to $\sigma(Z)$"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be that $E[XY|\sigma(Z)] = E[X|\sigma(Z)]E[Y|\sigma(Z)]$?

Comment: I think that would be conditionally uncorrelated.  I'm genuinely asking, though - what's the definition of conditionally independent you are working with?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is not true. If it were, you could take $C=\Omega$ and get that conditional independence implies independence, but that is not the case.

Comment: @JasonSwanson Oh, I didn't even think about that. Thank you for your insight.